# Multiplayer freezing at main menu

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Can someone help me? When I try to click multiplayer at the main menu on Black Ops 2 for Xbox 360 and I just can play zombies online and not multiplayer. When I try to click it when I want to play, it just freezes and I have to reset my Xbox and it just keep on doing that and before it did that to zombies and I could just play multiplayer online and now it is happening again.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score -1):

All I can suggest as far as what I would do is to contact either COD BO2 technical support (if there is one) or xbox customer support.

Aside from that, I can't help. Sorry, but I hope you can get this resolved!